# mousedown class for jQuery UI Resizable

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have a `div` I've made resizable using jQuery UI. It works fine, but I want to jazz it up a little by changing the `background-color` of the handle the user is currently using.

I know there are a bunch of classes for various parts of the resize interface (`ui-resizable-n`, `ui-resizable-sw`, `ui-resizable-handle`, etc.), but is there one specifically for `mousedown` events on handles? `ui-resizable-mousedown` or some such?

If not, I'm sure I can cobble a solution together, but obviously I'd prefer to just use the relevant jQuery UI class if one exists.

I did search around a bit, but I can't seem to find a full list of all the classes that apply to resizable elements. I assume it is somewhere in the jQuery UI docs, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ui-resizable-resizing` class, it's automatically added by JQuery UI.

Comment: ah, `-resizing`! Thank you! Is there a reference somewhere for these classes?

Comment: I didn't find anything with Google so I guess there isn't. I looked at chrome dom inspector while resizing and the class appeared!